# remove serial correlation using time series model in R or generally

Tags: r, time-series, arima, fgarch

I have a time series data of log returns and wish to remove the serial correlation so that I can model using either ARIMA and Garch model. The question is how do I approach the problem, there is two alternative (or atleast what I think) using ARIMA and choosing the residuals or decomposing.

I tried fiting an ARIMA model but the box jenkins test return a pvalue lower than 0.05, which still suggest serial correlation.

```
residuals_kcb=residuals(auto.arima(kcb_log$Log_returns))
Box.test(residuals_kcb,lag=10,type="Ljung-Box")
```

Comment: Things to try include analyzing diff(x) instead of x or taking every kth point where acf(x) will show at what k the correlations die down.